# Qt6とVisual C++ 2022でsjisファイルの扱いについての質問

Tags: qt, unicode, visual-c++

Qt5 と Visual C++ 2022 の環境では問題なくコンパイル/実行できているプロジェクトを、Qt6に移植しようとしていますが、日本語文字列でいくつかコンパイルエラーが出ます。

メッセージ等より、sjisでエンコードされているソースファイルをUTF-8だと思ってコンパイルしてソース中の日本語文字列でエラーを出しているようです。さらに調べるとコンパイルのコマンドラインに `/utf-8` というオプションを勝手に追加してこのような動作になっているようです。ソースファイルをUTF-8で保存しなおすとエラーが出なくなります。

プロジェクトのプロパティーのC/C++->すべてのオプションやコマンドラインをチェックしたのですが、`/utf-8` を指定している場所が分かりません。ただ、追加のオプションに `/source-charset:utf-8` とか指定すると、このオプションは `/utf-8` と一緒に使えませんというエラーになるので、`/utf-8` がどこかで指定されているのは間違いないように思います。Qt VS Toolsとかが悪さをしているのかなとも思ってます。

`/utf-8` をオプションから外し、sjisファイルをQt5の時のようにコンパイルできるようにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

まっとうな手段はすべてのソースをUTF-8に変換するということとは思いますが、何せいっぱいあるもんでちょっと躊躇しています。よろしくお願いします。

---

コメントいただきましたので、実際のエラーメッセージ等を追記します。

1>C:\Users\foo\source\boo.cpp(1,1): warning C4828: オフセット 0xa57 から始まる、現在のソースの文字セット (コードページ 65001) では使用できない文字がファイルに含まれています。

が、sjisのファイルすべてで複数出ています。で、

1>C:\Users\foo\source\boo.cpp(81,15): error C2001: 定数が 2 行目に続いています。

で、コンパイルが止まります。以上のメッセージはQt5版の方では出ていません。また、boo.cppをUTF-8で保存し直すとboo.cppに関するエラーは消えます。

試しにプロジェクトのプロパティー->C/C++->コマンドラインで、追加のオプションに `/source-charset:utf-8` を指定すると

1>cl : コマンド ライン  error D8016: コマンド ライン オプション '/utf-8' と '/source-charset:utf-8' は同時に指定できません

と出てビルドが失敗します。ただ、同じところのすべてのオプションは、

/permissive- /MP /ifcOutput "x64\Debug" /GS /W1 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_WINDOWS" /D "UNICODE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "WIN32" /D "_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE" /D "WIN64" /D "QT_OPENGLWIDGETS_LIB" /D "QT_WIDGETS_LIB" /D "QT_OPENGL_LIB" /D "QT_SVG_LIB" /D "QT_GUI_LIB" /D "QT_NETWORK_LIB" /D "QT_CONCURRENT_LIB" /D "QT_CORE_LIB" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug" /Fp"x64\Debug\boo.pch" /diagnostics:column

となっていて `/utf-8` は見当たりません。なお、`/I` オプションは上記では削除しました。`/D "UNICODE" /D "_UNICODE"` に関しては、問題の起きてないQt5版でもついているので問題ないと思ってます。「親またはプロジェクトの規定値から継承」のチェックマークを外しても症状は変わりません。その他、必要な情報がありましあらコメントで教えていただけると幸いです。

---

追記 #1

問題なくコンパイルできているQt5版でコンパイルオプションに `/utf-8` を追加してみたら、Qt6版と同様なエラーが出ました。よって問題はQt6版で `/utf-8` のオプションが追加されているのが問題だと思います。所詮Qt5->Qt6といってもライブラリーを変えただけだし、私はオプションを変えていないのでちょっと信じられないです。ただ考えられるとしたらQt VS Tools がQt6だと勝手に `/utf-8` をオプションに追加しているのではないかと疑っています。VSですべてのオプションとか表示しても、それは私が指定したものだけを表示しているだけで、それにさらに付け加えられてるのではないかなと疑っているのですが、どうでしょうかね？

---

追記 #2

CL.command.1.tlogでコンパイルオプション部分を抜き書きしたものが以下です。
`-utf-8` 以外にも追加されているものがあります。

/c /Zi /nologo /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _WINDOWS /D UNICODE /D _UNICODE /D WIN32 /D _ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE /D WIN64 /D QT_OPENGLWIDGETS_LIB /D QT_WIDGETS_LIB /D QT_OPENGL_LIB /D QT_SVG_LIB /D QT_GUI_LIB /D QT_NETWORK_LIB /D QT_CONCURRENT_LIB /D QT_CORE_LIB /Gm- /EHsc /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++17 /permissive- /Fo"X64\DEBUG\" /Fd"X64\DEBUG\VC143.PDB" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /wd4267 /FC -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:__cplusplus -Zc:externConstexpr -utf-8

Comment: この辺のツールを使って変換を試してみては？ [文字コード判定&変換ツール.NET](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se476748.html), [FileCode Checker](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dl/winnt/util/se478635.html), [ZiiDetector](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se488922.html), [Text Code Converter](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/util/se493100.html)

Comment: VS2015の記事ですがこんなのがあります。[New Options for Managing Character Sets in the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/)

Comment: @Hide117 すべてのファイルの文字コードが sjis であることは確定していますでしょうか？　それとも sjis のファイルと utf-8 のファイルが混在している状況ですか？

Comment: 質問者さんの感想は不要です。事実を整理して書いてください。例えば「プロジェクトのプロパティーのC/C++->すべてのオプションやコマンドラインをチェックした...」とせっかくチェックしたのに「...のですが/utf-8を指定してる場所が分かりません。」と感想しか書かれておらず、第三者には肝心のコマンドラインがどうなっていたのか読み取れません。具体的なコマンドラインを書くことで第三者にも判断できるようにしてください。またエラーが発生したのであれば、可能な限り忠実にエラーメッセージを貼り付けてください。

Comment: kunif さん ありがとうございます。リンク先を見てみます。

Comment: nekketsuuさん、sjisファイルと　utf-8ファイルが混在している状況です。

Comment: sayuriさん、すみませんでした。エラーメッセージ等を追加します。

Comment: `Qt5`で上手くいっていたプロジェクトの`.vcxproj`と、`Qt6`で問題のあるプロジェクトの`.vcxproj`のそれぞれのファイル全体の差分を取って内容をチェックしてみるとかどうでしょう？

Comment: kunif さん、コメントありがとうございます。早速比較してみました。詳細は省略しますが差分をチェックしてみましたが問題は見当たりませんでした。

Comment: `*.vcxproj`にはコンパイルオプションは直接書かれていなくてそこからインポートしているファイルに書かれているので、そのファイルを探しても`/utf-8`は書かれていないと思うのですが、`CL.command.1.tlog`には書かれているのですよね？

Comment: alpha さん、不勉強でCL.command.1.tlogのことは知りませんでした。今見たところ ”-utf-8” が書かれています。その他、「すべてのオプション」で出てきてないオプションも出てきてます。

Comment: ソースファイルに BOM がない場合にコンパイラないしは IDE が MBCS (CP932) 扱いしていて警告なってたり？ UTF-8 に変換したソースコードは BOM つきかどうかはわかりますか？

Comment: 問題はsjisファイルで発生していて、sjisをUTF-8だと思ってコンパイルしているから発生していると思うので、BOMの有無は関係ないと思うのですが、何か勘違いしてますかね？なお、UTF-8に変換する場合はBOMつきを指定してますが、全部そうかどうかは確認していません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt6.0で[`qt_allow_non_utf8_sources`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-allow-non-utf8-sources.html)というCMakeコマンドが導入されたようです。これの意味するところは、QtのソースコードのエンコーディングはUTF-8であるべきで、そうでない場合はこのコマンドで明示するようです。

ただし、これはCMakeを使用した場合であり、質問のQt VS Toolsの場合ではどのように扱われているかはわかりませんでした。しかし質問の状況から察するに、Qt VS ToolsにおいてもCMake側と同じようにソースコードはUTF-8であるとみなされ、コンパイルオプション `/utf-8` がどこかで指定されているのかもしれません。

---

> 私が指定したものだけを表示しているだけで、それにさらに付け加えられてるのではないかなと疑っている

その可能性はありそうです。これに関しては、 [[オプション] ダイアログ ボックス: [プロジェクトおよびソリューション] > [ビルド/実行]](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-projects-and-solutions-build-and-run?view=vs-2022) で **MSBuild プロジェクト ビルドの出力の詳細** でログレベルを変更することができます。ログレベルを上げると、実際に起動したコマンドラインを確認することができますので、その中に `/utf-8` など関係するオプションが指定されているか把握できます。

---

Qt Visual Studio Toolsの動作を確認しました。どこまで動作するかはわかりませんが、プロジェクトのプロパティに次の設定項目がありました。

- Additional Options
  Additional compiler options required by Qt. These options will be passed to the compiler, unless specifically excluded in the next field.

ここに`-utf-8`が指定されています。

- Excluded Options
  Options to exclude from the above compiler options required by Qt. These options will NOT be passed to the compiler. Prefix options with '/' or '-', and separate them with spaces.

ここに `-utf-8` を指定すると打ち消してくれるようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

> 私の環境だとAdditional Optionsが空欄で何も表示されない

Qt Visual Studio Toolsは非常に特殊な動きをしていましたので、説明をしておきます。

1. [次の内容で `x64\Debug\qmake\temp\qtvars.pro` を生成する](https://github.com/qt-labs/vstools/blob/v2.9.0/QtMSBuild/QtMsBuild/qt_vars.targets#L246-L294)

   ```
   CONFIG += no_fixpath
   QT += core
   ```
2. [`qmake qtvars.pro`を実行し`x64\Debug\qmake\temp\qtvars_x64_Debug.props` を生成する](https://github.com/qt-labs/vstools/blob/v2.9.0/QtMSBuild/QtMsBuild/qt_vars.targets#L311-L324)
   この中に`Qt_CL_OPTIONS_`が次のように定義されている。

   ```xml
   <Qt_CL_OPTIONS_>-Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -permissive- -Zc:__cplusplus -Zc:externConstexpr -utf-8</Qt_CL_OPTIONS_>
   ```
3. この`Qt_CL_OPTIONS_`が巡り巡って[`Cl`タスクの`AdditionalOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task?view=vs-2022)に設定される。

というわけで、Additional Optionsに値が表示されていなかったのは、当該構成でまだqmakeを実行しておらず、どのようなフラグが指定されることになるのか判明していなかったからだと思います。

Comment: こちらもやってみましたが、追記したように-utf-8が指定されていました。CMakeの話は参考になりました。UTF-8 であるべき、ということなんでしょうね。

Comment: @Hide117 で、本スレッドで質問された件について解決していないのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問は「/utf-8オプションを外せないか？」なので、もう少し待ちたいと思います。

Comment: Excluded Options  に-uft-8を追加することで、問題が出なくなりました。問題解決です。ありがとうございます。ただ、私の環境だとAdditional Optionsが空欄で何も表示されないんですよね。まあ、こちらは本質的な問題ではないので、無視することにします。

Comment: @Hide117 一応、補足しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

私の環境（VS2022 Qt6）では、プロジェクトのプロパティーのC/C++->コマンドラインの追加のオプションが

```
-Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -permissive- -Zc:__cplusplus -Zc:externConstexpr -utf-8 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458
```

このようになっていて、`-utf-8`と指定されています。
これが無いということでしょうか。

Comment: YAMAMOTOさん、「すべてのオプション」ではなく「追加のオプション」の欄ですよね？ 私の環境ではそこは空欄です。ただし、CL.command.1.tlogには-utf-8だけではなく、YAMAMOTOさんには見えている-Zc:rvalueCast 等々も出てくるので、実際のコマンドラインはYAMAMOTOさんが見ているものだと思います。VSの設定で私にはすべての情報が見えてなくて、YAMAMOTOさんには見えている、といった問題なのかなと思っているのですが、関係するような設定をご存じでしたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、-utf-8はYAMAMOTOさんが追加したものですか？それとも気が付いていたら指定されていた、って感じのものですか？ Qt VS Toolsはお使いですか？ cmakeあるいはqmakeをお使いですか？ 私は Qt VS Toolsを使ってますが、cmakeもqmakeも使っていません。そこがYAMAMOTOさんとの違いかなと思って質問しています。

Comment: Qt VS Tools の Open Qt Project File から .pro ファイルを開くと、「追加のオプション」欄に先のコメントのオプションが入っています。Qt VS Tools のバージョンは 2.9.1.6 です。

Comment: Visual Studio の以前のバージョンでは /utf-8 を指定するオプションの設定が個別に有ったように思うのですが、VS2022ではこの「追加のオプション」に指定するように書かれているので、他には無さそうな気がしますね・・・
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170#set-the-option-in-visual-studio-or-programmatically

Comment: 私は.proファイルを読み込んでVSの設定をする、というやり方をしていないので、挙動の違いが出てきたと思います。というか私の方の挙動はQt VS Toolsのバグみたいな気がしますね。バージョンは同じです。

Answer (score -1):

Adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/utf-8" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="/utf-8"` into CMake command line.